# Android Studio JAVA_HOME variable not working on Windows 8

Tags: android, java-home

I just installed Android Studio, and it asked me to set up my JAVA_HOME variable.  I set it to "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`" my `PATH` variable is set to "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin`" and when I type "`java -version`" in my command line I get "java version 1.8.0_20" so I know my JDK is working.  When I type "`echo %JAVA_HOME%`" in the command line I get "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20`" and when I type "`echo %PATH%`" I get "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin`" so I know those are working.  When I attempt to start Android Studio I get an error message that reads "No JVM installation found. Please install a 64 bit JDK."  If I change my `JAVA_HOME` variable to include the \bin I get an error saying the `JAVA_HOME` does not point to a valid installation of JDK.  I have looked all over the internet, and I have done everything exactly as every source I have found says to do it.  If anyone knows what I am doing wrong some help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm running windows 8.1 on a surface Pro 2 in case that matters.

Comment: Are you sure you have the 64-bit JDK installed and not the x86 version?

Comment: For 64-bit Windows: `C:\Program Files`: 64-bit programs, vs.   `C:\Program Files (x86)`: 32-bit programs.  You've set your JAVA_HOME to a 32-bit version of Java.  Install the 64-bit version (if you don't already have it), change JAVA_HOME ... and also check your registry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the 32-bit jdk with a 64-bit version of AndroidStudio. You should download and install java for 64-bit computers and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows. 8 is 64 bit or 32 bit from the above error post it apears you might have downloaded 32 bit jdk for 64 bit os. But your other setting(setting environmental variable) is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I downloaded the x86 instead of the 64 bit.